# How do I save a file using the response header filename with cURL?

Tags: curl

This question relates to the command line version of cURL.

I'm trying to download a file from a CGI script.

```
http://example.com/perl/dl.pl?ID=2
```

Using a browser the filename comes up as `remotefilename.gz`.
cURL wants to save the file as `dl.pl?ID=2`.

How do I get cURL to save to a file with the filename from the response header?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

[-J/--remote-header-name](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-J) is the option you want.

You use -J in conjunction with [-O](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-O), which makes curl use the file name part from the URL as its primary way to name the output file and then if there is a Content-disposition: header in the response, curl will use that name instead.

Comment: have in mind that you should use -J/--remote-header-name in conjunction with -O/--remote-name option otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: `-OJ` is a killer option, that's easy to remember :)

Comment: It's worth noting that `-J/--remote-header-name` doesn't work if the URL doesn't contain the scheme (`http://` or `https://`): https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/760.

Comment: Considering the @jchook's comment to another answer I see it's handy to remember `-JLO` mnemonic which looks prettier:)

Comment: You can also add -f if you don't want curl to create a file when the server returns a 404.  ...although it won't be as easy to remember as either -OJ or -JLO.  :)

Comment: I couldn't save the **Google Drive** files with their native names until I shared them to "everyone with the link can view"

Comment: Not work when `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''filename`,  in this case, use `wget --content-disposition URL`

Comment: Do we have any option for overwriting existing file with same name?

Comment: Doesn't work for example for https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/geckodriver/download/

Answer (score 25):

```
curl http://example.com/dl.php?file=3123123 -O -J
```

if server uses redirection use these:

```
--location-trusted
--max-redirs 10
```

Comment: Be careful with `--location-trusted` since it will forward HTTP auth information to redirects, even across different domains. `--location` seems like a safer option.

Answer (score 23):

`curl -OJ` gave me segmentation fault: 11 error when attempting to download multiple URLs at once.

Instead, I used `wget`. The latest version supports HTTP Content-Disposition headers, which often contain filename information.

```
wget --content-disposition http://example.com/download/url
```

Answer (score -9):

you can try the `-o` or `-O` option.

Comment: -o Asks for a filename to save to
-O saves to disk as dl.pl?ID=2