# How do I preserve the remote filename when Downloading a file using curl

Tags: shell, scripting, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I save a file using the response header filename with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698552/how-do-i-save-a-file-using-the-response-header-filename-with-curl)

I need to download many thousands of images in the format

http://oregondigital.org/cgi-bin/showfile.exe?CISOROOT=/baseball&CISOPTR=0

If you paste that link in a browser, it tries to download a file named 1.jp2

I want to use curl to do the same. However, when I run

curl -I 'http://oregondigital.org/cgi-bin/showfile.exe?CISOROOT=/baseball&CISOPTR=0'

the filename is reported as 404.txt which you can download and see that it is actually the file I want. I can't use the -O option because the name assigned to the file is no good, and I have technical reasons for needing the actual name used on the system.

How do I get curl to download the same file I have no trouble retrieving in my browser? Thanks.

Comment: my guess is that this is somehow related to the user-agent of the caller, though I just tried it adding chrome's UA and that didn't help.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The solution is to use `-O -J`

> ```
> -O, --remote-name          Write output to a file named as the remote file  
> -J, --remote-header-name   Use the header-provided filename
> ```

So...

```
curl  -O -J  'http://oregondigital.org/cgi-bin/showfile.exe?CISOROOT=/baseball&CISOPTR=0'
```

I had to upgrade my CURL. I had v 7.19 which doesn't support -J but 7.22 (which is the latest) does.

Comment: You can write `-OJ`. Or e.g. `-LOJR` if you combine with other options

Comment: As per [7.20.0 § curl - Changes](https://curl.se/changes.html#7_20_0), the `-J` or `--remote-header-name` option is added in 7.20.0 .

Comment: Solely `--remote-name` is sufficient.

Comment: But keep in mind that it may don't work if the server uses UTF-8 in `Content-Disposition`. Because some cURL versions does not handle it correctly. At least curl 7.84.0 for macOS does not.

Comment: You may use `wget` as an alternative in this case. ```wget --content-disposition <URL>```

Comment: The parameter `-J` was a tricky one. I was trying to download a file from a local Node server app I built. Couldn't figure out why the file was getting saved with the url part and not the filename in header.

Thanks @YevgenySimkin for this

Answer (score -8):

You can use the -o option can you? eg

```
 curl  'http://oregondigital.org/cgi-bin/showfile.exe?CISOROOT=/baseball&CISOPTR=[0-9]' -o "#1.jpg"
```

Comment: he says right in his question that he can't use the -O because he doesn't want the file name to be showfile.exe?... etc.  Pay Attention! :)

Comment: the user can't define the file name in this case... it's coming from the header of the incoming response

Comment: -o lets you set a custom name and more importantly, a custom location for the downloaded file. -O automatically names the file, but also downloads it to the default location (my home folder in my case). So how would I combine the two, and choose where the file gets downloaded, but preserving the name from the server?