# How do I save a file using the response header filename with cURL, based on the *redirected* response header

Tags: curl

Similar to [How do I save a file using the response header filename with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698552/how-do-i-save-a-file-using-the-response-header-filename-with-curl) but the server doesn't actually return the file (& Content-Disposition header), but rather a redirect to another server that does. This causes cURL to effectively ignore the J option. So the flow is:

```
curl https://example.com/redirect-me-to-my-file -LOJ
-> Redirect (no Content-Disposition) to https://otherexample.com/here-is-my-file
-> File + Content-Disposition header
```

This causes cURL to save the file as "redirect-me-to-my-file", not what's in the Content-Disposition header. Doing the download in e.g. Chrome leads to the intended filename.

**Is there a way to work around this?**

(The order of the L, O, and J command line options appears to not impact the result, and when I add -v I can see the lack of Content-Disposition in the first response, and the presence of it in the redirected response)

Comment: curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

Comment: Try upgrading your curl version. I tried this on `curl 7.24.0 ` and it works fine [uses the disposition field on the redirect] by using `-LOJ`. I did try this with `http` and not `https`.