# prepare file for curl download

Tags: php, csv, curl

I am trying to create a script that will create a csv and be downloaded from a client via curl.

my client sends:

```
 curl -0 1.2.3.4/index.php?param=1
```

my script index.php does some fun stuff and ends up with a csv:

```
 1,2,3,4
 5,6,7,8
```

i can get the data to print to screen, just cant get csv sent to client.
I tried:

```
 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
 $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
 $row = "1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8\n";
 fputcsv($output, $row);
```

but that fails.  nothing happens. i return to command prompt on client. any thoughts?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/fputcsv. the function expects an **ARRAY**. You're not providing an array - you're passing in a string. since you've already built the CSV yourself, there is **NO** point in using fputcsv. YOu could just as well have used `echo $row`

Comment: ok, so i got that figured out.  now how can i get the file name to be data.csv I have tried curl -oJ also tried -OJ and -O -J and still get index.php

Comment: from SO found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698552/how-do-i-save-a-file-using-the-response-header-filename-with-curl

Comment: if $row is the csv contents, so the only thing that you have to do is : print $row. remove fopen and fputcsv