# How can I download linked PDF files that begin .pl and download default name?

Tags: curl, wget

I'm working my way through the United States Court of Appeals For the Seventh Circuit and grabbing RSS links for monitoring and automatically downloading the pdf files of Judicial Opinions.

The current system is throwing me a problem. Luckily I was able to get the system to dump (output) all 15,967 Judicial Opinions from 10/28/1999 - 12/30/2020 using the following link:

http://media.ca7.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Time=month&FromMonth=01&FromDay=01&FromYear=1998&ToMonth=&ToDay=&ToYear=&Author=any&AuthorName=&Case=any&CaseY1=&CaseY2=&CaseN1=&CaseN2=&CaseN3=&CaseN4=&Submit=Submit&RssJudgeName=Sykes&OpsOnly=yes

The links for the document download's per case is structured such as the following:

http://media.ca7.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Submit=Display&Path=Y2020/D12-30/C:20-1779:J:Flaum:aut:T:fnOp:N:2636910:S:0

I am not too familiar working with cgi-bin / .pl rss configuration(s) and system(s).

I used the following Mozilla Firefox Extensions to mass open 1000 opinion(s) at a time:

SnapLinks: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/snaplinksplus/

URLs List: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/urls-list/

My take on this was to mass open 1,000 opinion's at a time. Build a linklist and then run a mass WGET query against the .txt file I was going to paste them into.

However, when using CURL manually with it's most basic syntax's for a get file and WGET, failed me trying to download the following Single Judicial Opinion:

http://media.ca7.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Submit=Display&Path=Y2019/D06-24/C:18-2169:J:Brennan:aut:T:fnOp:N:2360043:S:0

**WGET attempt**:

```
brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/WGET.1$ wget (LINK5)

After Enter in Terminal:
[2] 3130

brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/WGET.1$ 
Redirecting output to ‘wget-log’.

brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/WGET.1$ ls
'rssExec.pl?Submit=Display'   wget-log
brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/WGET.1$ tail -f wget-log
Resolving media.ca7.uscourts.gov (media.ca7.uscourts.gov)... 63.241.41.178
Connecting to media.ca7.uscourts.gov (media.ca7.uscourts.gov)|63.241.41.178|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/pdf]
Saving to: ‘rssExec.pl?Submit=Display’

rssExec.pl?Submit     [ <=>         ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-12-30 18:27:27 (0.00 B/s) - ‘rssExec.pl?Submit=Display’ saved [0]
```

**CURL** Attempt:

```
brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/CURL.1$ curl (LINK5)

After Enter in Terminal:
[2] 3154

brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/CURL.1$ ls
[2]-  Done                    
brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/CURL.1$ ls
brandon@icedragon:~/CURL/7thCir.1/CURL.1$
```

If anyone has any suggestions; I was originally hoping to bring the RSS into Thunderbird and then duplicate the RSS links into PHP eventually and somehow let Python manage the data and then pass it back out to PHP. (Larger Goal eventually).

Comment: You're asking about a failing command, but you don't even show the command... How are we supposed to help? // `[2] 3154` is showing you didn't properly quote/escape the `&` in your URLs for the shell.

Comment: ikegami; Thank you for this comment. I was not aware that terminal outputs code that could be referenced. I honestly had no idea what [2] 3154 meant. After reading your comment; I ran wget "http://media.ca7.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Submit=Display&Path=Y2019/D06-24/C:18-2169:J:Brennan:aut:T:fnOp:N:2360043:S:0" and it downloaded perfectly and opened in Okular without an error. Thank you!

Comment: You need to put your url in quotes, symbols like `&` can be interpreted by the shell in other way (this case you spawn other failing process). Please edit your question

Comment: @Mobrine Hayde; Thank you! Since ikegami let me know, it works. I don't know how to solve the question as answered for comments. I am very new to stackoverflow. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

### Fixing your shell problem

People have already shown that your first mistake was not protecting shell metacharacters. The `&` on the command line tells the shell to put the job in the background. That `[2] 3154` is the job number in brackets and the process ID. Fix that with quotes around command:

```
% curl '...url...'
```

That lets you make the request, but now the trick is to get the filename. This particular example makes it a bit tough:

### A little about HTTP

In short, you make a request and you don't care what the URL looks like. You don't have to know anything about the remote server, Perl, and so on. You make the request and get a response. It's up to you do handle the response.

In this case, you are hitting a script that supplies a response with the PDF. But, it might return something else.

In such a response, the `Content-Disposition` can suggest a filename.  Normally, `curl` could save the file for you (`-O`) with that suggested filename by using the `-J` switch (see also [How do I save a file using the response header filename with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2701808/2766176)):

```
% curl -J -O '...'
```

Apparently, this service isn't using `Content-Disposition` so you can't get the filename from that:

```
$ curl -i 'http://media.ca7.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Submit=Display&Path=Y2019/D06-24/C:18-2169:J:Brennan:aut:T:fnOp:N:2360043:S:0'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 17:40:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.1.1g
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Without the suggested filename, `curl -J -O` creates a file name like `C:20-1779:J:Flaum:aut:T:fnOp:N:2636910:S:0`, which might be good enough for you. The case number, date, and author are there. You probably want to add a `.pdf` there.

You could post-process that filename to get something shorter.  The case number might be good enough, like `20-1779.pdf`.

### Working harder

Before you go through this part, note that this probably isn't a sustainable method for this task. [GovInfo has APIs](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts) to get you the stuff you need so you don't have to rely on a particular circuit's services.

But let's do it anyway because it's instructive to the general task and it's easy. You want to make a database of this stuff, so you probably need this info anyway when you display this stuff to people. (Note that if that's what you are doing, you are essentially taking on PACER, and they aren't particularly nice about that sort of thing).

Note that the link has much of the information that might be interesting for a file name. The case number, date, and author are there. The other letters probably have meaning, so it looks like you are only missing the caption.

You have the starting table (definitely not RSS) that has the case names in it. I'd parse that table, associate the case name with the download link, then save the response and rename it however you like.

I don't use those Mozilla extensions, so I don't know how you'd use them to solve this problem.

I did whip up this Mojolicious program in Perl, and other programming languages have similar tools (Python has BeautifulSoup, and probably others). I write about this stuff in [Mojo Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients). That book not only explains the tools, but what's going on and why you have to do things a certain way.

I navigate the DOM of the HTML to find the right table rows, then extract the table columns. Their HTML is not that sophisticated (no classes or ids), but at least I can identity the right table and rows. This is fragile because it breaks if they change their HTML.

I put that all the cases the big data structure. The form I chose is not important and you can make it anyway that you like, or even insert it into your database right away. It's not that I do something particular with the data, but that I can get the data. Once you have it, do whatever you need to do.

With these sorts of tasks, you're likely to mess stuff up in the middle, so you don't want to start all over when your process is interrupted. Being partial to Mojolicious, I think I'd insert these links into a [Minion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minion) job queue and then process that queue appropriately so the site operators don't ban me.

Not only that, but you are likely to run this again to get new cases. You don't want to redo anything you've already done.

```
#!perl
use v5.12;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::Util qw(dumper trim);

my $url = 'http://media.ca7.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Time=month&FromMonth=01&FromDay=01&FromYear=1998&ToMonth=&ToDay=&ToYear=&Author=any&AuthorName=&Case=any&CaseY1=&CaseY2=&CaseN1=&CaseN2=&CaseN3=&CaseN4=&Submit=Submit&RssJudgeName=Sykes&OpsOnly=yes';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $results = $ua
    ->get( $url )
    ->result
    ->dom
    ->find( 'tr[bgcolor]' )
    ->map( sub {
        my $row = $_;
        my( $case_number, $caption, $case_type, $file, $author )
            = map {
                eval { trim($row->at( ":nth-child($_)" )->all_text) }
                } qw( 1 2 3 4 6 );
        my $link = eval { $row->at( "td:nth-child(5) a" )->attr('href') };
        return {
            case_number => $case_number,
            caption     => $caption,
            case_type   => $case_type,
            file        => $file,
            author      => $author,
            link        => $link,
            }
        } )
    ->to_array;

say dumper( $results );
```

The output is like:

```
[
  {
    "author" => "Flaum",
    "caption" => "Paula McAllister v. \x{a0} Innovation Ventures, LLC",
    "case_number" => "20-1779",
    "case_type" => "civil",
    "file" => "12/30/2020",
    "link" => "/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Submit=Display&Path=Y2020/D12-30/C:20-1779:J:Flaum:aut:T:fnOp:N:2636910:S:0"
  },
  {
    "author" => "PerCuriam",
    "caption" => "USA v. \x{a0} Eduardo Ramirez",
    "case_number" => "20-1006",
    "case_type" => "criminal",
    "file" => "12/29/2020",
    "link" => "/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Submit=Display&Path=Y2020/D12-29/C:20-1006:J:PerCuriam:aut:T:fnOp:N:2636244:S:0"
  },
  {
    "author" => "St__Eve",
    "caption" => "USA v. \x{a0} Jermaine Stamps",
    "case_number" => "20-1336",
    "case_type" => "criminal",
    "file" => "12/29/2020",
    "link" => "/cgi-bin/rssExec.pl?Submit=Display&Path=Y2020/D12-29/C:20-1336:J:St__Eve:aut:T:fnOp:N:2635847:S:0"
  },
...
]
```

Comment: I think you mean [Minion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minion) not Mango

Comment: @brian d foy, Thank you extensively for this thorough answer! I am catching up and sorry for the delay on acknowledgement and gratitude! Best Regards! - Brandon (I do not know perl); I will look further into getting BeautifulSoup4 working. Database always fails for me.